# Contents overlap on footer while print page preview

Tags: jquery, html, css

I m trying to implement some code that will create the headers and footers on all of my web pages but contents overlapping on footer.

**My Stylesheet:**

```
 <style>

    @media print
    {

        #Header
        {
            display: block;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0pt;
            left: 0pt;
            right: 0pt;
            font-size: 200%;
        }

        #Footer
        {
            display: block;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0pt;
            left: 0pt;
            right: 0pt;
            font-size: 200%;
            page-break-before: always;
        }

        #form
        {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            top: 0.5in;
            left: 0pt;
            bottom: 0.5in;
            right: 0pt;
        }

    }
</style>
```

My Header, content & footer div
in content insert more then A4 size lines to break page in print preview.

```
 <div class="wordcontent">
    <div class="" style="height: 0.5in;" contenteditable="true" id="Header">
        HEADER
    </div>
    <div id="form" name="formDiv" contenteditable="true" style="min-height: 10in;">
     content more then 500 lines
    </div>
    <div class="" style="height: 0.5in; margin-top: 5px;" contenteditable="true" id="Footer">
        FOOTER
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting problem. The issue is that the form and the headers/footers take up the same space, and there is no "paged padding" you can apply to the #form that would work on every page. I tried giving the @page a larger bottom margin, and the footer a negative `bottom` value, but that won't work; stuff that would end up in the page margin is not printed. So I'm interested in possible solutions that turn up.

Comment: hello friends any one have solution for this problem?? It is possible?

Answer (score -1):

You better change the page-break-after to content because you are going to change the content not the footer footer will be fixed and page breaks after every content and new page content follow the top property to fall below the header

here is the code pen [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvLReZ)

```css
 @media print
    {

        #Header
        {
            display: block;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0pt;
            left: 0pt;
            right: 0pt;
            font-size: 200%;
        }

        #Footer
        {
            display: block;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0pt;
            left: 0pt;
            right: 0pt;
            font-size: 200%;
            
        }

       #form
        {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            top: 0.5in;
            left: 0pt;
            bottom: 0.5in;
            right: 0pt;
          page-break-after: always;
        }

    }
```

```html
 <div class="wordcontent">
    <div class="" style="height: 0.5in;" contenteditable="true" id="Header">
        HEADER
    </div>
    <div id="form" name="formDiv" contenteditable="true" style="min-height: 10in;">
     content more then 500 lines
    </div>
   <div id="form" name="formDiv" contenteditable="true" style="min-height: 10in;">
     content more then 500 lines
    </div>
   <div id="form" name="formDiv" contenteditable="true" style="min-height: 10in;">
     content more then 500 lines
    </div>
    <div class="" style="height: 0.5in; margin-top: 5px;" contenteditable="true" id="Footer">
        FOOTER
    </div>
</div>
```